# How to edit the text of a SVG file?

Tags: svg

I want to translate the labels of a [wikimedia Commons SVG file.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Harp.svg) After opening a SVG file in [a Geany text editor](https://www.geany.org/), i do search and replace option for put the translations. In this case,  i cant find relaxant text?  But there is text Id only as below. How can i find the text?

**Examples for SVG files:-**

1) code with text from the [this file](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%22FIRED!%22_stamp.svg)

```
<text x="-34.614517" y="314.04907" transform="matrix(0.90850818,-0.41786707,0.41786707,0.90850818,0,0)"><tspan style="font-size:108px;fill:#ff0000;font-family:Courier">FIRED!</tspan></text>
```

2) code without text from [the mentioned SVG file link:](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Harp.svg)

```
<text
 xml:space="preserve"
 style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;text-align:justify;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;writing-mode:lr;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;"
 x="523.21991"
 y="135.43217"
 id="text3578"
 sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspan
   sodipodi:role="line"
   id="tspan3582" /></text>
```

Comment: there is no text, all the letters are drawn using shapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Robert Longson mentions there is no text.

All elements are drawn:

[image: Harp.svg]

If you open the .SVG file with [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) you will be able to see all objects